# How to transpose data in text?

Tags: python, transpose

I can not transpose my text data the right way and replace the `','` with `' '` generating a new text file.

My text is:

0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0011, 0.00066, 0.00137, 0.00079, 0.00071, 0.00141, 0.0, 0.00182, 0.00151, 0.00077,
0.00166, 0.00242, 0.0061, 0.01112, 0.0, 0.01417, 0.00414, 0.00228, 0.0027, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.01248, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06371, 0.00448, 0.0, 0.01182, 0.0,
0.01938, 0.06195, 0.00791, 0.0, 0.05479, 0.00646, 0.05939, 0.02536, 0.06581, 0.00146,
0.0, 0.10148, 0.00858, 0.05245, 0.03534, 0.02738, 0.0, 0.01521, 0.02567, 0.01389,
0.0, 0.01177, 0.11606, 0.41767, 0.17797, 0.02097, 0.04637, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01696,
0.03828, 0.03649, 0.01519, 0.0465, 0.04523, 0.0, 0.11382, 0.03256, 0.239, 0.06641,
0.00726, 0.0, 0.02342, 0.03302, 0.11531, 0.0, 0.33871, 0.21537, 0.0, 0.19708,
1.08416, 0.03333, 0.01763, 0.25371, 0.01275, 0.31206, 0.0, 0.07271, 0.06306, 0.05016,
0.00482, 0.11395, 0.0, 0.14741, 0.04568, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.16177, 0.00628,
0.05526, 0.07857, 0.41543, 0.0172, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.28001, 0.01096, 0.0,
0.0, 0.14767, 0.0, 0.88451, 0.11258, 0.57063, 0.23525, 0.19962, 0.10215, 0.12147,
0.15307, 0.06756, 0.20032, 0.0, 0.38074, 0.0, 0.30569, 0.0, 0.14491, 0.01522,
0.15175, 0.0, 0.47177, 0.09829, 0.13909, 0.21286, 0.0, 0.38484, 0.06639, 0.0,
0.25202, 0.21179, 0.82245, 0.4142, 0.0, 0.08601, 0.56517, 0.0, 0.59679, 0.23728,
0.04749, 0.29558, 0.24965, 0.0, 0.0, 0.22227, 0.72755, 0.62913, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.19146, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2144, 0.77099, 0.0, 0.37493, 0.89662,
0.47225, 0.43947, 0.12473, 0.35669, 0.10165, 0.45582, 0.22459, 0.29898, 0.0, 0.56291,
0.96687, 0.0, 0.3302, 0.86844, 0.06221, 0.77419, 0.17999, 0.65999, 0.2328, 0.0,
0.16307, 0.76734, 0.52557, 0.26596, 0.0, 0.0, 0.27549, 0.43434, 0.25947, 0.01236,
0.0, 0.42255, 0.5073, 0.38113, 0.10205, 0.45306, 0.00477, 0.0, 0.37107, 0.14947,
0.27564, 0.70923, 0.0562, 0.05902, 0.21613, 0.25713, 0.39205, 0.0, 0.0, 0.43975,
0.70342, 0.0, 0.50664, 0.11172, 0.10631, 0.05909, 0.79553, 0.1349, 0.07048, 0.0,
0.53473, 0.0, 0.0, 0.31553, 0.48961, 0.0, 0.06141, 0.38112, 1.22286, 0.33563,
0.19423, 0.06941, 0.2862, 0.0343, 0.64844, 0.17025, 0.0, 0.62452, 0.0, 0.0,
0.08317, 0.0, 0.10109, 0.09981, 0.0, 0.369, 0.01377, 0.18212, 0.13574, 0.37456,
0.03428, 0.34665, 0.47843, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0053, 0.23513, 0.0, 0.13714, 0.0,
0.05245, 0.32722, 0.0, 0.05677, 0.31737, 0.10693, 0.62225, 0.53793, 0.20858, 0.04239,
0.35165, 0.02668, 0.0, 0.03544, 0.27847, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04481, 0.0, 0.16931,
0.01964, 0.0, 0.01786, 0.24306, 8e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02659, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0599, 0.41067, 0.0, 0.00589, 0.17132, 0.09665, 0.39494, 0.0, 0.0, 0.08364,
0.07752, 0.00266, 1e-05, 0.07468, 0.0, 0.00754, 0.19101, 0.28241, 0.0, 0.07648,
0.02461, 0.0, 0.36781, 0.14567, 0.00504, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02592, 0.01688, 0.06218,
0.0, 0.01588, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01979, 0.30657, 0.15687, 0.00331, 0.04598, 0.04678,
0.0, 0.0, 0.36563, 0.07478, 0.17633, 0.08055, 0.0, 0.0097, 0.0, 0.0,
0.01385, 0.00765, 0.12829, 0.0679, 0.1493, 0.01366, 0.07352, 0.01161, 0.0267, 0.05016,
0.09829, 0.0705, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04273, 0.0, 0.0716, 0.04736, 0.00187, 0.04349,
0.05556, 0.00092, 0.0, 0.0052, 0.05377, 0.0004, 0.02759, 0.0, 0.0, 0.61669,
0.02357, 0.01095, 0.00227, 0.55783, 0.0, 0.08453, 0.12306, 0.0, 0.04116, 0.0,
0.00134, 0.59121, 0.0, 0.01725, 0.0011, 0.00079, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00968, 0.04991,
0.03231, 0.0, 0.02791, 0.0, 0.12359, 0.16621, 3e-05, 0.0, 0.04995, 0.01438,
0.06546, 0.0, 7e-05, 0.0, 0.07103, 0.00683, 0.01083, 1e-05, 0.01107, 0.00693,
0.0, 0.06917, 0.0, 0.01422, 0.0343, 0.0, 0.00705, 0.34537, 0.0, 0.01165,
0.00372, 0.2154, 0.57886, 0.08228, 0.00332, 0.0735, 0.0, 0.05252, 0.03644, 0.03541,
0.23112, 0.01512, 0.0, 0.09462, 0.00031, 0.06564, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01107,
0.00034, 7e-05, 0.12024, 0.01307, 3e-05, 0.0789, 0.02932, 0.0, 0.32752, 0.45147,
0.0, 0.22466, 0.0, 0.02007, 0.00872, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-05, 0.36416, 0.00015,
0.19467, 0.0, 0.0, 0.53572, 0.32223, 0.12186, 0.0483, 0.00779, 0.3339, 0.00013,
0.00082, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10405, 0.0, 0.4502, 0.0051, 0.08296,
0.00216, 0.04353, 0.12367, 0.0, 0.14389, 0.0, 0.0, 0.36673, 0.0, 0.0,
0.34636, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.01351, 0.00034, 0.01907, 0.00791, 0.0, 0.00129, 0.0,
0.40499, 0.0, 0.0, 0.08366, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25584, 0.57061, 0.70507, 0.0,
0.0, 0.18143, 0.42539, 0.66514, 0.0, 0.0, 0.29804, 0.0, 0.28829, 0.41273,
0.50942, 0.0, 0.09178, 0.20272, 0.41303, 6e-05, 0.02448, 0.48811, 0.0, 0.0818,
0.0, 0.07639, 0.65981, 0.00096, 0.0, 0.22846, 0.70347, 0.43426, 0.0, 0.40663,
0.01652, 0.09416, 0.0, 0.02656, 0.56497, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03001, 0.0,
0.71715, 0.0, 0.00192, 0.47048, 0.22631, 0.0, 0.02586, 0.06006, 0.20732, 0.01805,
0.13912, 0.54863, 0.0, 0.51657, 0.00743, 0.10778, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.67212, 0.19832, 0.00432, 0.0, 0.00175, 0.06667, 0.41716, 0.12217, 0.31288,
0.0, 0.74852, 0.0, 0.00255, 0.2814, 0.45116, 0.50539, 0.32614, 0.0, 0.30409,
0.0, 0.0, 0.25113, 0.0, 0.22741, 0.1391, 0.02574, 0.00016, 0.0073, 0.45934,
0.23991, 0.02004, 0.34749, 0.0, 0.52377, 0.06326, 0.32335, 0.16302, 0.15746, 0.00364,
0.0, 0.54827, 0.42714, 0.70166, 0.0, 0.0, 0.39795, 0.06715, 0.0, 0.0,
0.23439, 0.00604, 0.20924, 0.1957, 0.39783, 0.0, 0.0, 0.51778, 0.0, 0.0,
0.57082, 0.0, 0.00024, 0.0, 0.74322, 0.00116, 0.0, 0.16356, 0.01133, 0.02243,
0.65346, 0.7895, 0.30318, 0.52492, 0.18114, 0.53485, 0.22016, 2e-05, 0.39816, 0.56479,
0.02864, 0.65234, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0992, 0.14987, 0.0, 0.0, 0.07462,
0.16234, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00621, 0.05237, 0.78129, 0.43683, 0.12717, 0.15497, 0.25109,
0.4028, 0.0, 0.2481, 0.84632, 0.00093, 0.02692, 0.0, 0.0, 0.42843, 0.04238,
0.05716, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.61904, 0.02759, 0.0, 0.0878, 0.19206, 0.61152,
0.0388, 0.23548, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00666, 0.13364, 0.22438, 0.0, 0.63356, 0.36131,
0.457, 0.15553, 0.0, 0.0, 0.02199, 0.00631, 0.1607, 0.47493, 0.01608, 0.0,
0.86933, 0.51457, 0.17658, 0.00092, 0.00659, 0.00155, 0.0, 0.67375, 0.63718, 0.00635,
0.39418, 0.61056, 0.0, 0.0, 0.37985, 0.15329, 0.63039, 0.28826, 0.04915, 0.48761,
0.57095, 0.0, 0.70731, 0.40762, 0.0006, 0.67333, 0.48771, 0.0, 0.17767, 0.30208,
0.41305, 0.66482, 0.47214, 0.51383, 0.0, 0.30166, 0.01172, 0.11783, 0.36782, 0.0,
0.71679, 0.0, 0.00053, 0.0, 0.75962, 0.47075, 7e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.00012, 0.73663, 0.17536, 0.5773, 0.00318, 0.51136, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00075, 0.00515,
0.47188, 0.41978, 0.78495, 0.14351, 0.00491, 0.0, 0.21411, 0.77982, 0.65693, 0.51292,
0.4017, 0.10142, 0.18035, 0.51624, 0.50906, 0.0, 0.4748, 0.26747, 0.0, 0.23534,
0.0, 0.59324, 0.00676, 0.20496, 0.77803, 0.00729, 0.57775, 0.58682, 0.0, 0.0,
0.26202, 0.54766, 0.11304, 0.00739, 0.01078, 0.00026, 0.00019, 0.0, 0.0552, 0.00478,
0.00887, 0.00143, 0.88311, 0.12395, 0.60467, 0.88719, 0.01793, 0.27321, 0.0071, 0.28893,
0.00426, 0.0135, 0.0, 0.26657, 0.69537, 0.70755, 0.0, 0.5103, 0.73724, 0.00547,
0.62234, 0.0, 0.86454, 0.25019, 0.11372, 0.0, 0.0, 0.48168, 0.01546, 0.04045,
0.03804, 0.22293, 0.02279, 0.00311, 0.38029, 0.01809, 0.0, 0.45164, 0.05918, 0.40769,
0.45002, 0.36323, 0.0, 0.0, 0.40397, 0.00262, 0.0, 0.78498, 0.40938, 0.91316,
0.71599, 0.46511, 0.85203, 0.7996, 0.04825, 0.0, 0.09025, 0.72207, 0.47213, 0.82834,
0.16914, 0.20413, 0.40483, 2e-05, 0.0133, 0.026, 0.0143, 0.22382, 0.81758, 0.54883,
0.00738, 0.0, 0.15307, 0.54968, 0.0, 0.52159, 0.25367, 0.0, 0.68786, 0.41812,
0.43675, 0.0, 0.81874, 0.17509, 0.88778, 0.63771, 0.0, 0.64224, 0.0, 0.0,
0.69858, 0.47271, 0.0, 0.21959, 0.15844, 0.67096, 0.70144, 0.78685, 0.63303, 0.00156,
0.66517, 0.24494, 0.78376, 0.78629, 0.32911, 0.14563, 0.00711, 0.02871, 0.18767, 0.8961,
0.0, 0.58092, 0.8437, 0.30775, 0.74901, 0.45169, 0.0, 0.0, 2e-05, 0.16325,
0.00027, 0.20422, 0.0, 0.92263, 0.84271, 0.84346, 0.64423, 0.0658, 0.55896, 0.04355,
0.0538, 0.19018, 0.82118, 0.0, 0.27977, 0.0, 0.74302, 0.67848, 0.50665, 0.67587,
0.84453, 0.74089, 0.60708, 0.47972, 0.69295, 0.61686, 0.09719, 0.69716, 0.8583, 0.0,
8e-05, 0.24042, 0.17525, 0.07163, 0.31539, 0.80091, 0.87077, 0.98207, 0.64515, 0.6948,
0.00125, 0.02975, 0.90463, 0.00303, 0.0, 0.93436, 0.66711, 0.01799, 0.9924, 0.85188,
0.85912, 0.87112, 0.01973, 0.63834, 0.64741, 0.06465, 0.06521, 0.42098, 0.73724, 0.31299,
0.88215, 0.90051, 0.81997, 0.95985, 0.33599, 0.40494, 0.88442, 0.0, 0.0, 0.83327,
0.79802, 0.35831, 0.01498, 0.9909, 0.08315, 0.66085, 0.66397, 0.94616, 0.81412, 0.83521,
0.95701, 0.72068, 8e-05, 0.62333, 0.09822, 0.76215, 0.87812, 0.93228, 0.00033, 0.0,
0.81552, 0.51051, 0.91455, 0.0, 0.00024, 0.83926, 0.13759, 0.26159, 0.60253, 0.01088,
0.71392, 0.10763, 0.89284, 0.3285, 0.08792, 0.0, 0.85177, 0.79829, 0.87048, 0.65896,
0.82504, 0.76809, 0.38868, 0.50562, 0.69606, 0.83334, 0.31914, 0.27777, 0.78106, 6e-05,
0.0, 0.93466, 0.74669, 0.60927, 0.1728, 0.19641, 0.2739, 0.92478, 0.96385, 0.0,
0.69251, 0.9082, 0.70993, 3e-05, 0.0, 0.75534, 0.08925, 0.50013, 0.59023, 0.01423,
2e-05, 0.12135, 0.85847, 0.00164, 0.8859, 0.00246, 0.51261, 0.30216, 0.86809, 0.69494,
0.00247, 0.89602, 0.59868, 7e-05, 0.91897, 0.64267, 0.91627, 0.23151, 0.44279, 0.79596,
0.01885, 0.29243, 0.28422, 0.99603, 0.91255, 0.67915, 0.89201, 0.77753, 0.60719, 0.95975,
0.18137, 0.1546, 0.64383, 0.96593, 0.19669, 0.82404, 0.98231, 0.27302, 0.18805, 0.0,
0.68261, 0.6296, 0.02293, 0.0, 0.9731, 0.08581, 0.62543, 0.76949, 0.66724, 0.88789,
0.92198, 0.75583, 0.96611, 0.00115, 0.93666, 0.68866, 0.89657, 0.71895, 0.0, 0.94766,
0.96108, 0.40706, 0.95828, 0.0, 0.81978, 0.95118, 0.84892, 0.88329, 0.78456, 0.97352,
0.68649, 0.42083, 0.41782, 0.09697, 0.79667, 0.88364, 0.83115, 0.8813, 0.99415, 0.6738,
0.98341, 0.94438, 0.80001, 0.0, 0.77804, 0.84052, 0.29258, 0.73352, 0.97524, 0.98193,
0.0, 0.02012, 0.97543, 0.96822, 0.81253, 0.77312, 0.24458, 0.93977, 0.76052, 0.60103,
0.91787, 0.98777, 0.76958, 0.76331, 0.71286, 0.87532, 0.6658, 0.4996, 0.0, 0.64545,
0.80568, 0.85656, 0.94331, 0.99354, 0.54307, 0.74909, 0.95161, 0.98588, 0.13247, 0.0,
0.21857, 0.96922, 0.99133, 0.96473, 0.66736, 0.93286, 0.98603, 0.15018, 0.70267, 0.01198,
0.9812, 0.43031, 0.97368, 0.94333, 0.72137, 0.98418, 0.93496, 0.62019, 0.0, 0.99945,
0.89992, 0.71041, 0.6212, 0.52375, 0.3942, 0.67067, 0.92295, 0.98456, 0.98564, 0.8758,
0.99463, 0.94381, 0.94382, 0.7784, 0.1628, 0.90346, 0.00042, 0.98292, 0.97309, 0.69548,
0.96029, 0.0, 0.96545, 0.80257, 0.00023, 0.95191, 0.94038, 0.82768, 0.8995, 0.98584,
0.6277, 0.82213, 0.95606, 0.98726, 0.13339, 0.00032, 0.98997, 0.93163, 0.89086, 0.99028,
0.96303, 0.88884, 0.99528, 0.13969, 0.77352, 0.85036, 0.94541, 0.59115, 0.98512, 0.95694,
0.81543, 0.28429, 0.99578, 0.98808, 0.85223, 0.15575, 0.33364, 0.97604, 0.99155, 0.90054,
0.99208, 0.60712, 0.98134, 0.93541, 1.00718, 0.9823, 0.97079, 0.66414, 0.302, 0.69145,
0.9932, 0.97381, 0.68745, 1.0001, 0.98088, 0.79647, 0.9238, 1.01026, 0.00391, 0.97843,
0.91765, 0.71654, 0.99149, 0.97218, 0.32367, 0.99139, 0.97472, 0.86509, 0.03768, 0.02374,
0.18801, 0.79787, 0.97795, 0.8347, 0.82799, 0.61118, 1.00187, 0.99989, 0.98515, 0.97909,
0.91595, 0.10959, 0.93512, 1.00562, 0.0, 0.69003, 0.98077, 0.7465, 0.97714, 0.9966,
0.99787, 0.99578, 0.97794, 0.60312, 0.99176, 0.95949, 0.6999, 0.97356, 0.96904, 0.0573,
0.13452, 0.97716, 0.96954, 0.99246, 0.21391, 0.9728, 0.98404, 0.5172, 1.00339, 0.91114,
0.00465, 0.51447, 0.63154, 0.69188, 0.92773, 0.99777, 0.88507, 0.40716, 0.99545, 0.95278,
0.98608, 0.8262, 0.99037, 0.96644, 0.93059, 0.98848, 0.98699, 0.96161, 0.65182, 0.97904,
0.98335, 0.69846, 0.98946, 0.80262, 0.9762, 0.53884, 0.81839, 0.992, 0.99598, 0.97057,
0.98038, 0.8616, 0.97676, 0.82606, 0.99322, 0.65537, 0.48884, 1.00215, 0.98887, 0.8692,
0.21477, 0.88879, 0.6925, 0.64932, 0.99068, 1.00011, 0.98418, 0.96835, 0.99108, 0.96094,
0.93733, 0.99821, 0.98724, 0.43077, 0.99156, 1.00126, 0.80593, 0.60752, 0.99285, 0.99398,
0.9992, 0.98307, 0.94107, 0.88788, 1.00109, 0.0001, 0.96391, 0.77974, 0.97745, 0.97589,
0.93147, 0.97971, 0.01167, 0.0, 0.99202, 0.97259, 0.65711, 0.94732, 0.80932, 0.70469,
0.93707, 0.02118, 0.99943, 0.99637, 0.92242, 0.24604, 0.16671, 0.84163, 0.9094, 0.07028,
0.94006, 0.98469, 0.43973, 0.69326, 0.99743, 0.91469, 0.72106, 0.77641, 0.99696, 0.98408,
0.13681, 0.96954, 0.99383, 0.97266, 0.95387, 0.96465, 0.8625, 0.0, 0.9841, 0.98199,
0.97234, 0.76364, 0.08237, 0.99373, 1.00036, 1.00343, 0.17298, 0.72534, 0.9788, 0.8565,
0.0, 0.99744, 0.94527, 0.98732, 0.05989, 0.61549, 0.97663, 1.00705, 0.13951, 0.99877,
0.99125, 0.9255, 0.98095, 0.91349, 0.44588, 0.76609, 0.92098, 0.90367, 0.9631, 0.48437,
0.98063, 0.94242, 0.95703, 0.51909, 0.87705, 0.9849, 0.99502, 0.96808, 0.01861, 1.00171,
0.02385, 0.93644, 0.99133, 0.43765, 0.92777, 1.00347, 0.95968, 0.66915, 0.93299, 0.00205,
0.22353, 0.33501, 0.73898, 0.95762, 0.01194, 0.79213, 0.0, 0.58841, 0.87265, 0.95764,
0.27127, 0.00073, 0.99685, 0.94511, 0.98494, 0.34793, 0.80683, 0.157, 0.55023, 0.91874,
0.98894, 0.25268, 0.87803, 0.0005, 0.57588, 0.13271, 0.13509, 0.72093, 0.98285, 0.95108,
0.04568, 0.92865, 0.9179, 0.97505, 0.86268, 0.8409, 0.92861, 0.28239, 0.93964, 0.15543,
0.84762, 0.8012, 0.79349, 0.0, 0.19849, 0.60645, 0.95696, 0.83704, 0.91742, 0.80044,
0.87414, 0.7175, 0.99337, 0.72689, 0.99542, 0.99566, 0.79942, 0.98478, 0.89981, 0.8228,
0.85063, 0.65399, 0.73885, 0.98612, 0.96821, 0.88325, 0.961, 0.93603, 0.59629, 0.89733,
0.05871, 0.99015, 0.02122, 0.84649, 0.76339, 0.9411, 0.77132, 0.70793, 0.95945, 0.84496,
0.93305, 0.58042, 0.90098, 0.8566, 0.79814, 0.9118, 0.9368, 0.01079, 0.94997, 0.8792

It should be transpose like this new text:

```
0.0 0.00038 0.00404 0.0 ...
0.0 0.00034 0.00579 0.01225 ...
0.0 0.0 0.01083 0.03703 ...
....
```

Comment: Read it in, and convert it to a matrix (first split on newline, then split on white space).  Then it should be easy to transpose it.

Comment: Is the original text data in a file?

Answer (score 0):

It has been figured out by this script:
ary = np.genfromtxt('phonon2.txt')

## one value per line

np.savetxt('foo.txt', ary[:,0:1])

## all the values in one line

np.savetxt('foo1.txt', ary[:,0:1].T)